# Typescript/tslint not complaining about this in arrow function

Tags: typescript, react-native, tslint

After some creative refactoring I ended up with this:

```
const TopBar = () => (
  <Button
    onPress={this.onPress} // Not complaining
  />
)
```

All the other rules I set up in `tslint.json` are working as expected.

How can enforce `typescript`/`tslint` to complain in this case?

I am using `"typescript": "^3.3.3333"` on a `React Native` project

Answer (score 1):

I had to add inside of `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` the following rule:
`"noImplicitThis": true`